# svg + div mouseover popup

Tags: css, svg

hej there.

i created an svg from a complex image, showing a city map. including tiny green boxes to mark certain houses, etc. with A,B,C or other. (can be seen in screenshot)
on mouseover, a div box should appear (with more than a tooltip-line - as shown in the screenshot and by code) - positioned within the viewbox and next to the pointer.
alternatively it could be an overlay - centered within the viewbox - that disappears when moving the pointer away from the anker.

*i was not able to achieve this with plain css, working with combined #C .mark #markc (for example) and visibility.*

SVG-'box':

```
<g id="C">
    <rect class="cls-245" x="88.2" y="523.4" width="11.2" height="9.26"/>
    <g class="cls-2"><path class="cls-6" d="M92.9,528.7c0,.9.4,1.4,1,1.4s.9-.4.9-1h1.3v.2a2,2,0,0,1-2.2,1.9,2.2,2.2,0,0,1-2.3-2.5v-.6a2.2,2.2,0,0,1,2.3-2.5,2,2,0,0,1,2.2,1.9v.2H94.8c0-.6-.3-1-.9-1s-1,.5-1,1.4Z"/></g>
  </g>
```

DIV to appear:

```
  <div class="mark" id="markc">
  <div class="thead">
      <div class="pin">C</div> <div class="label">culpepper crescent</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tdetail">
  <p class="descrp">Bewohner</p>
  <p class="peops">Heathcote Barbbary<br>Lynn Stark</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS code:

```
#karte {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    border: #fff solid 10px;
    outline: #ceccc4 solid 1px;
}

.mark {
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    line-height: 110%;
    font-weight: normal;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
}

.thead {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-position-y: bottom;
    font-family: Roboto Slab;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.pin {
    background-color: #4e9295;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
}

.label {
    background-color: #D6EBEC;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

.tdetail {
    background: #E9E9E9;
    color: #4d4e52;
    font-family: calibri;
    min-height: 75px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-top: 8px solid #fff;
}

.tdetail .descrp {
    color: #4d4e52;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.tdetail .peops {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

it is supposed to be a 'present'. i have nearly no experience with javascript - i am happy to use it as a solution, but might need a 'clear' instruction. it is up to 25 'pins' on the complete map.

many thanks!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZe9X.png)

Comment: Is the popup div supposed to be shown at the bottom (as in your screenshot)?  Or is it supposed to be next to the pointer as in normal tooltips?

Comment: ah, missed. this. thanks! :) it is supposed to be next to the pointer. if not - it would be preferred as an overlay within the viewbox (centered) that can be closed on moving the pointer away from the pin 'box' (green A,B,C,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple example implementation to get you started.

You'll need to do a little more work to make it work with more than one tooltip.  Not also that it assumes your map is at 1:1. If your SVG has a viewBox or is otherwise scaled, you need to do some work to get the correct coordinates to show the tooltip at.  You can find out how to do that by searching Stack Overflow.

```js
var C = document.getElementById("C");

// Add an event handler to C that fires when the mouse moves over it
C.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
  let markc = document.getElementById("markc");
  // Position the tooltip element near the mouse
  markc.style.left = (evt.offsetX + 10) + "px";
  markc.style.top = evt.offsetY + "px";
  // Show the tooltip element
  markc.classList.remove("hidden");
});

// Add an event handler to C that fires when the mouse leaves the element
C.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
  hideElement("markc");
});


// Hide the element with given id
function hideElement(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.add("hidden");
}

// Start out with the tooltip hidden
hideElement("markc");
```

```css
#karte {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    border: #fff solid 10px;
    outline: #ceccc4 solid 1px;
}

.mark {
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: absolute;   /* changed to absolute so we can position it where we want */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    line-height: 110%;
    font-weight: normal;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
}

.thead {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-position-y: bottom;
    font-family: Roboto Slab;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.pin {
    background-color: #4e9295;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
}

.label {
    background-color: #D6EBEC;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

.tdetail {
    background: #E9E9E9;
    color: #4d4e52;
    font-family: calibri;
    min-height: 75px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-top: 8px solid #fff;
}

.tdetail .descrp {
    color: #4d4e52;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.tdetail .peops {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px;
}



.cls-245 {
  fill: green;
}

.cls-6 {
  fill: white;
}

/* Needs to be position relative so we can later position the tooltip relative to it. */
.container {
  position: relative;
}

/* class used to hide the tooltip when we don't want it showing */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <svg width="400" height="700">
    <g id="C">
      <rect class="cls-245" x="88.2" y="523.4" width="11.2" height="9.26"/>
      <g class="cls-2"><path class="cls-6" d="M92.9,528.7c0,.9.4,1.4,1,1.4s.9-.4.9-1h1.3v.2a2,2,0,0,1-2.2,1.9,2.2,2.2,0,0,1-2.3-2.5v-.6a2.2,2.2,0,0,1,2.3-2.5,2,2,0,0,1,2.2,1.9v.2H94.8c0-.6-.3-1-.9-1s-1,.5-1,1.4Z"/></g>
    </g>
  </svg>

  <div class="mark" id="markc">
    <div class="thead">
      <div class="pin">C</div>
      <div class="label">culpepper crescent</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tdetail">
      <p class="descrp">Bewohner</p>
      <p class="peops">Heathcote Barbbary<br>Lynn Stark</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a million @paul-lebeau! the mousout does not work though. I tried filling it but must have failed - markc does show the whole time. on mousover, it jumps up to C and does not disappear any more. 

`C.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
  hideElement("markc");
});`

it tells me 'evt is defined but never used' and I did fail on filling in 'id's correctly.

Comment: Do you mean my example is not working for you?  It works for me in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: correct, the div with id 'markc' is not hidden by default and does not hide on mouseout. i tried your solution only and the combination with my complete code. in chrome. dreamweaver gives me only the hint that i stated above. thank you for the response, though. much appreciated.

Comment: Does my example work by itself?  If so, then obviously there must be something wrong with the way you integrated my solution to your code.   I can't really help you debug code that I cannot see :).  Check that you don't have duplicate `id` attributes. Or CSS that interferes.  Use the browser dev tools to help you work out what is happening.

Comment: :) totally agree. i checked the code on it's own (what i meant by 'tried your solution, only') - but it did not work. running the snippet here in stackoverflow worked, though. -- FINALLY was able to reproduce the mistake: i took the '.hidden' in css to the top of my css file. it has to be right at the bottom of the sheet. :D THANK YOU!!!